# off screen hamburger navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I am trying to create a right sided off screen navigation. Something similar to [this](http://botondraduly.com/). I am following this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/) but making modifications on my own.

I am building this in `reactjs` and `CSS`.

I am currently having trouble getting the frontend to look/behave the same way as [this](http://botondraduly.com/). I think it may be that I am not css selecting the right tags with `.nav-trigger:checked + .site`.

I want the `<ul>` to be hidden when the label is unchecked. When it is checked, the `<label>` will move to the left 215px and the element with `.site` will move 200px to the right, displaying the underlying `<ul>`.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumemaka/jwm6k66c/):

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

- At the start hide your nav and show only hamburger icon. You can do it with `transform: translateX()`. You can use `display: none`, but `display: none` you can't animate.
- Then on clicking on the hamburger icon change the state to `true` (depending on state value, we'll render a class to show the nav).
- Then render an var (for example `open`), which will be empty if `this.state.open` is false (nav div will have only `nav` class)

  `let open = this.state.open ? "open" : "";`
- and if `this.state.open` is true, then the var open would be `open` (nav div will have two classes `nav` and `open`).

You can do something like this :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
          this.state = {
            open: false
          }
    }
    
    toggleNav(){
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    }
    
    render(){
        let open = this.state.open ? "open" : "";
        return (
        <div>
            <div className={`nav ${open}`}>
               <div className="icon">
                   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png" onClick={this.toggleNav.bind(this)}/>   
               </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And add the css as follows :

```
.nav{
  width: 200px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-208px);
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.icon img{
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
}

.open{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

[Here is a fiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1524/)